# Deserializing xml to list object returning null

Tags: c#, xml, xml-deserialization

I'm trying to deserialize xml data using xmlreader into a list object but I am getting a null back from my call. Here is a sample of my xml data...

```
<ExceptionLog>
    <ExceptionLogData MessageCount="1" SourceDateTime="2016-02-08T09:32:41.713" MinSourceDateTime="2016-02-08T09:32:41.713" DataId="610029" MaxExceptionLogID="610029" MessageText="INVALID_SESSION_ID: Invalid Session ID found in SessionHeader: Illegal Session. Session not found, missing session hash: hX7K7LONeTilw5RfGT432g==&#xA;This is expected, it can happen if the session has expired and swept away, or if the user logs out, or if its just someone trying to hack in. " MachineName="VERTEXDPORTSQL1" AppDomainName="VTMS.Windows.SalesforceServicingAgent.exe" ProcessName="VTMS.Windows.SalesforceServicingAgent" />
    <ExceptionLogData MessageCount="1" SourceDateTime="2016-02-08T09:22:39.340" MinSourceDateTime="2016-02-08T09:22:39.340" DataId="610028" MaxExceptionLogID="610028" MessageText="INVALID_SESSION_ID: Invalid Session ID found in SessionHeader: Illegal Session. Session not found, missing session hash: rtZTrLk2f99iVttLoz31tg==&#xA;This is expected, it can happen if the session has expired and swept away, or if the user logs out, or if its just someone trying to hack in. " MachineName="VERTEXDPORTSQL1" AppDomainName="VTMS.Windows.SalesforceServicingAgent.exe" ProcessName="VTMS.Windows.SalesforceServicingAgent" />
</ExceptionLog>
```

This is the object class code that I am trying to create...

```
public class ExceptionLog {
    public ExceptionLog() {
        ExceptionLogData = new List<ExceptionLogExceptionLogData>();
    }

    public List<ExceptionLogExceptionLogData> ExceptionLogData { get; set; }
}

public class ExceptionLogExceptionLogData {
    private DateTime _sourceDateTimeField;

    private DateTime _minSourceDateTimeField;

    private uint dataIdField;

    private uint _maxExceptionLogIdField;

    private string _messageTextField;

    private string _machineNameField;

    private string _appDomainNameField;

    private string _processNameField;

    public byte MessageCount { get; set; }

    public DateTime SourceDateTime {
        get {
            return _sourceDateTimeField;
        }
        set {
            _sourceDateTimeField = value;
        }
    }

    public DateTime MinSourceDateTime {
        get {
            return _minSourceDateTimeField;
        }
        set {
            _minSourceDateTimeField = value;
        }
    }

    public uint DataId {
        get {
            return dataIdField;
        }
        set {
            dataIdField = value;
        }
    }

    public uint MaxExceptionLogID {
        get {
            return _maxExceptionLogIdField;
        }
        set {
            _maxExceptionLogIdField = value;
        }
    }

    public string MessageText {
        get {
            return _messageTextField;
        }
        set {
            _messageTextField = value;
        }
    }

    public string MachineName {
        get {
            return _machineNameField;
        }
        set {
            _machineNameField = value;
        }
    }

    public string AppDomainName {
        get {
            return _appDomainNameField;
        }
        set {
            _appDomainNameField = value;
        }
    }

    public string ProcessName {
        get {
            return _processNameField;
        }
        set {
            _processNameField = value;
        }
    }
}
```

And finally here is how I am trying to deserialize the data...

```
        using (var dataReader = sqlCommand.ExecuteXmlReader())
        {
            var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ExceptionLog));

            var returnDataList = serializer.Deserialize(dataReader) as List<ExceptionLogExceptionLogData>;
            return returnDataList;
        }
```

What have I missed or what am I doing wrong?

I have another approach that I can use until I figure this out and that is the old fashioned way of creating my object list and programmatically populating it with my objects on the fly - not very graceful but for the time being it works.

TIA

Answer (score 0):

XmlSerializer is defined of type ExceptionLog but you're then casting the result to List

```
var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ExceptionLog));
var returnDataList = serializer.Deserialize(dataReader) as List<ExceptionLogExceptionLogData>;
```

The casting should be to the type of serializer:

```
var returnDataList = serializer.Deserialize(dataReader) as ExceptionLog;
```

I didn't check all the elements but you should also mark ExceptionLogData with XmlElement attribute.

```
[XmlElement]
public List<ExceptionLogExceptionLogData> ExceptionLogData { get; set; }
```

There might be some issues with the other properties but this should address the problem in the question

Comment: <p>That did it! Thank you so much.</p>I also went in and added [XmlAttribute] to all of my public properties and now everything is working fine.

Comment: @B.Youngmman: Excellent, I'm glad it worked out for you. You can also accept the answer if it helped solve your issue.